# Window menus stick under window name. How to fix this?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

After experimenting with desktop environments and uninstalling and installing unity desktop all window menus are sticking under the window name

[image]

Switching the window menu behavior has no effect.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the menus.
I uninstalled `indicator-appmenu` and reinstalled it with

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu
```

It seemed to have been missing some dependencies.